# Does Redis have a get ‘N geographically closest’ capability?

Tags: redis, geospatial

I’ve been working with GEORADIUS and the suite of functions but I’m curious if there’s a way to get the 100 closest members in a Z sorted GEORADIUS key.

For instance... I don’t know how many members are geographically close to a known member, so I don’t know how large of a radius to use with GEORADIUS in order to get 100 of the closest members.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 3):

Redis' GEO support is limited. There's no such command, and you need to do it on the client side:

1. Use `1` meter as the radius to check if there're enough items.
2. If there're enough items, get the `N` closest items from the result.
3. If there're NOT enough items, double the radius, and goto step 1.

Answer (score 1):

JaguarDB has very strong support of geospatial data (2D and 3D). It allows you to store multi-measurements per point location while other databases support only one measurement (pointm). Many complex queries such as KNN, Voronoi polygon, convexhull are also supported. It is open source. The KNN k nearest neighbor query can help you. It also supports vector shapes in addition to raster shapes like linestrings polygons.